# Nock - Get number of calls performed to fetch

Tags: unit-testing, fetch, nock, react-custom-hooks, fetch-mock

I've got a React custom hook that tries to avoid repeated calls to a URL. This is done by storing in state the `isLoading` prop, which is set to `true` whenever the fetch method is called, and is set to `false` once it receives the response from the server.

To test it, I need to be able to count how many times 'fetch' has been called, but I cannot seem to find any option or property or method inside `nock` library that gets me that.

There is a `isDone` method to know if all mocks have been fulfilled. There is a `pendingMocks` to know how many mocks haven't been fulfilled. But I can't find a way to count how many times `fetch` has been called, without caring about anything else (just the URL match).

They may be 100 times or just 2, just want to check how many times `fetch` has been called, just like `toHaveFetchedTimes` in `fetch-mock-jest`. Is there any way to do so in `nock`?

Comment: Did you find a way ?

Comment: @ThomasChampion nope, actually had to switch back to `fetch-mock-jest` because of this. It's less intuitive and sometimes things are hard to configure, but it has some functionalities that I need and `nock` hasn't.

Answer (score 3):

I find a way that works even it's not very clean.

In fact `reply` can take a callback function in second parameter that is called for every request that matches criteria.

```js
  let called = 0
  nock
    .post('/my/path')
    .reply(200, () => {
      called++
      return { foo: 'bar' }
    })

  expect(called).toBe(1)
```

See: https://github.com/nock/nock#specifying-replies